# How to extend to an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/48 \cong C_{48}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Can you give feedback on my work? Any help would be appreciated!

Let $C_{48}= \langle x\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order $48$. For which integers
        $a$ does the map $\phi_a$ defined by $\overline{1}\mapsto x^a$ extend to an
        isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/48 \cong C_{48}$?

We claim that $\{a \in \mathbb{Z} : 1 \leq a \leq 47, (a, 48)=1 \}$ works. We show $\phi_a$ is isomorphism by
        showing it is bijective.

First, we show $\phi_a$ is surjective.
        Suppose $(a,48)=1$. Take, $x^k \in C_{48}$ such that $0 \leq k \leq 47$. If $\phi(g)=x$, for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}/48$
        then we show it is surjective since $C_{48}=\langle x \rangle$.
        We know by the Euclidean algorithm $1=k_1 \cdot 48 + k_2 \cdot a$ for some integers $k_1$ and $k_2$. 
        Then,
        \begin{align}
   x &= x^{k_1 \cdot 48 + k_2 \cdot a} \\
   &= (x^{48})^{k_1}(x^a)^{k_2} \\
   &=(x^a)^{48q+r} \\
   &= (x^a)^r   
  \end{align} 
        Where in $(6)$ the division algorithm was used to show that there exists $q$ and $r$ such that $0 \leq r < 48$.
        Therefore, $\phi_a(r)=\phi_a(1+1+...+1)=x$ where in the second equality $1$ is added $r$ times.
        Hence, $\phi_a$ is surjective.

Second, we show $\phi_a$ is injective by showing $\ker\phi_a=\{1\}$. Since $\phi_a$ is homomorphism, $\phi_a(0)=1$.
        Suppose to the contrary there exists $g \in \mathbb{Z}/48$ such that $g \neq 0$ and $\phi(g)=1$. 
        Note, $1 \leq g \leq 47$. 
        Then, $\phi_a(g) = \phi_a(1)\phi_a(1)...\phi_a(1) = (x^a)^g =1$ where the second equality holds because $\phi$ is
        homomorphism. Hence $48$ divides $ag$. Then, contradiction as $(a,48)=1$ and $g \leq 47$.

Comment: Actually the set should just be $\{a\in\Bbb Z:(a,48)=1\}$, the bounds $1\le a\le 47$ are not necessary. Also I think the question would be clearer if you used $n$ instead of $48$, nothing makes $48$ special in this question.